# integer expression expected testing or condition in if else bash scripts

Tags: bash, if-statement

In a shell script I wrote following lines gave error during execution of script

```
if [ p -eq 35 -o p -eq 70 ]; then
echo "Sleeping ....zzz ........zzzz......."
sleep 5
```

get following error

```
/d2.sh: line 6: [: p: integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `$p` instead of `p`:

```
if [ $p -eq 35 -o $p -eq 70 ]; then
    ...
```

Comment: You can use variable names without `$` only in `(( ... ))` arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @l0b0: No, `[[ ]]` still requires `$` to expand variables.  @choroba: Note that you need to use different operators inside `(( ))`: `==`, `<`, `>`, `||` etc instead of `-eq`, `-lt`, `-gt`, `-o`...

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson for your nice advice... as I am searching so many websites how can I get rid of this integer problem.